# Java POST data to mySQL UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: java, mysql, post, encoding, utf-8

I have POST data that contains the Japanese string `AKB48 ネ申テレビ シーズン3`, defined in jQuery as `data`.

```
$("#some_div").load("someurl", { data : "AKB48 ネ申テレビ シーズン3"})
```

The post data is sent to Java Servlet:

```
String data = new String(this.request.getParameter("data").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

My program saves it to MySQL, but after the data is saved to the database it becomes:

> AKB48 u30CDu7533u30C6u30ECu30D3 u30B7u30FCu30BAu30F33

What should I do if I want to save it as it is in UTF-8? All my files are in UTF-8.

MySQL encoding is utf8 and here is the code

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Inventory (uid, item_id, item_data, ctime) VALUES ("
                + inventory.getUid() + ",'"
                + inventory.getItemId() + "','"
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(inventory.getItemData()) + "',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    int cnt = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: is your mysql database in utf8?  How are you persisting to mysql, straight SQL or hibernate etc? And also, since it is saving the codepoints correctly, it could be that you are just viewing it incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example above, I can verify that the Japanese string is getting saved to your MySQL database correctly, but as [escaped Unicode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Syntax/Unicode_Escape_Sequences).

I would check these items in order:

1. Are your tables and columns all set to have a character set and collation for utf8?  I.e.,
   `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`
2. Are explicitly setting the character set encoding before POST? `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`
3. Are you setting the character encoding for your db connections? I.e., `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOURDB?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8`

As the others have pointed out, you should not use that `getBytes` trick. It will surely mess up the POSTed values.

**EDIT**

Do not use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava`, since that will turn your string into escaped Unicode. That is what is transforming `AKB48 ネ申テレビ シーズン3` into `AKB48 u30CDu7533u30C6u30ECu30D3 u30B7u30FCu30BAu30F33`.

Comment: I did step 1 and 2 but not 3 because I'm using    DataSource dc = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/databasename");
 kind of connection

Comment: @bn., my point 3 is to explicitly set the character set encoding for your database connections. If you do not do this, you are likely saving the data to the database with an incorrect encoding. `(DataSource)ctx.lookup` is for locating your data source, which is a completely different matter. I strongly suggest you reexamine how your database connections are being created.

Comment: You need to set them as connection properties in your datasource config. Oh, and please get rid of all `new String(string, charset)` and `string.getBytes(charset)` nonsense.

Comment: ya it was because of escaped string problem and also I need to use preparedStatement

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not just extract value of parameter like `this.request.getParameter("data")`?

Your data is sent correctly using URL encoding where each unicode character is replaced by its code. Then you have to get the value of the parameter. When you are requesting bytes using `ISO-8859-1` you are actually corrupting your data because the string is represented as a sequence if codes in textual form.

Comment: While it would corrupt some data, his characters are out of the scope of curropting characters.  So that's not the problem in this example.  He's getting the correct codepoints saved to his MYSQL so we can see it's being interpreted correctly.  But I'm with alex that you should use `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in your tomcat setup and just let that handle the parameter encoding.

Comment: I wasn't aware jquery load used a post.  `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of the line

```
String data = new String(this.request.getParameter("data").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

You're transforming chinese (or at least non-occidental) characters into bytes using the ISO-8859-1 encoding. Of course this can't work, since chinese characters are not supported by the ISO-8859-1 encoding. ANd then you're constructing a new String from bytes that are supposed to represent ISO-8859-1-encoded characters, using the UTF-8 encoding. This, once again, doesn't make any sense. UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 are not the same thing, and only a small set of chars have the same encoding in both formats.

Just use

```
String data = this.request.getParameter("data");
```

and everything should be OK, provided that the column in the MySQL table uses an encoding that supports these characters.

EDIT:

now that you've shown us the code used to insert the data in database, I know where all this comes from (the preceding points are still valid, though). You're doing

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(inventory.getItemData())
```

What's the point? `escapeJava` is used to take a String and escape special characters in order to make it a valid Java String literal. It has nothing to do with SQL. Use a prepared statement:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Inventory (uid, item_id, item_data, ctime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement();
stmt.setInteger(1, inventory.getUid()); // or setLong, depending on the type
stmt.setString(2, inventory.getItemId());
stmt.setString(inventory.getItemData());
int cnt = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

The PreparedStatement will take care of escaping special SQL characters correctly. They're the best tool agains SQL injection attack, and should always be used when a query has parameters, especially if the parameters come from the end user. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Comment: If I use only String data = this.request.getParameter("data");
it becomes something different like: AKB48 u00E3u0083u008Du00E7u0094u00B3u00E3u0083u0086u00E3u0083u00ACu00E3u0083u0093 u00E3u0082u00B7u00E3u0083u00BCu00E3u0082u00BAu00E3u0083u00B33

Comment: tell us the encoding of the MySQL column, and show us the code used to save the String in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Java strings are stored in UTF-16. So, this code:

```
String data = new String(this.request.getParameter("data").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

decodes a UTF-16 string (which has been re-encoded from UTF-8 in the HTTP protocol) into a binary array using the ISO-8859-1 charset, and re-encodes the binary array using the UTF-8 charset. This is almost certainly not what you want.

What happens when you use this?

```
String data = this.request.getParameter("data");
System.out.println(data);
```

If the second line generates bad data, then your problem is likely in jQuery. Determine that you are indeed getting unicode in your jQuery request:

```
System.out.println(this.request.getHeader("Content-Encoding"));
```

If it does not generate bad data, but the data doesn't get stored correctly in mySQL, your problem is at the database level. Make sure your column type supports unicode strings.

Comment: System.out.println(this.request.getHeader("Content-Encoding"));
 returns me null